# Why 'IF' condition return true for the 0 compared to string in PHP? and how the string parsed as zero?

Tags: php, string, variables, if-statement

I faced the below scenario that happened with my web application. I need a exact reason and solution for this

```
<?php
$var = 0;
if ($var == "StringVal") {
    echo $var;
    echo "Wrong";
} else {
    echo "Right";
}
?>
```

these code must print

> Right

, But it print

> 0Wrong

What are the possibilities of this problem ?

Comment: $var = 'StringVal' is the only manner to make this work. You assign the value 0 to the $var, and that is not the same as 'StringVal'.

Comment: i am checking the 0 value with the string, are you seen the code or not...

Comment: @SathishKumarD Check my answer. When you compare an int with a string the string is converted into an int so "StringVal" would be converted to 0 as it is not a valid number and then 0 == 0 returns true.

Comment: I tahnk Osama Sayed has the right answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `==` for comparison in php. Use `===` instead.

This way you enforce a type check and this will work as expected. See [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for a PHP type comparison tables. There you see that a "Loose comparisons with ==" between e.g. 0 (int) and "php" (string) will return true. Which is not what one would expect.

Comment: its really working with the type conversion. but how both are made as equal as true

Comment: @SathishKumarD Because if `StringVal` is cast directly to int it's cast to 0 so you are comparing `0 == 0`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

So `var_dump(0 == "a");` Would return true as Php tries to parse "a" to a number, if the parsing fails which happens in this case, it returns 0 and then 0 is equal to 0. To overcome this compare the type as well using `===`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, after the parsing it will be zero.